# To install Gnufind in OSX?

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew

I run

```
brew search gnufind
```

and I get

```
No formula found for "gnufind".
Searching pull requests..
```

so no gnufind with the request.

I think it must have a different name.
I run

```
brew search find
```

and I get

```
ffind        findutils    frag_find    pathfinder
findbugs     flawfinder   fuzzy-find   rdfind
homebrew/games/robotfindskitten
Caskroom/cask/a-better-finder-attributes
Caskroom/cask/a-better-finder-rename
Caskroom/cask/easyfind
Caskroom/cask/find-any-file
Caskroom/cask/findings
Caskroom/cask/keyfinder
Caskroom/cask/neofinder
Caskroom/cask/path-finder
Caskroom/cask/qfinder
Caskroom/cask/refresh-finder
Caskroom/cask/totalfinder
Caskroom/cask/xtrafinder
```

I browse the commands by `brew info [package]` and find that the package *findutils* is maintained by GNU. 
I run `brew install findutils`. 
The package provides commands such as *find* and *locate*, docs [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/).

I do `hash -r` but no commands updated in my system like *g'find* or *find'g*.

**How can you install gnufind to your system?**

Comment: I've rolled back your edit: Rehashing/indexing is not the issue here, also the sites works better if you don't put the answer into the question text.

Comment: New thread here http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/179448/slow-indexing-and-hashing-in-nearly-low-memory-yosemite

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The commands are provided with a g prefix:

```
Mithos:~ verence$ ls -l /usr/local/Cellar/findutils/4.4.2/bin
total 1328
-r-xr-xr-x  1 verence  admin  233400 Nov 13 05:03 gfind
-r-xr-xr-x  1 verence  admin  143620 Nov 13 05:03 glocate
-r-xr-xr-x  1 verence  admin  229704 Nov 13 05:03 goldfind
-r-xr-xr-x  1 verence  admin    9837 Apr  3 15:09 gupdatedb
-r-xr-xr-x  1 verence  admin   49796 Nov 13 05:03 gxargs
Mithos:~ verence$ type gfind
gfind is /usr/local/bin/gfind
```

If this is the first time you are using `brew` to install software, make sure to include `/usr/local/bin` in your `PATH`. There is no need to add other paths for `brew`.

Comment: You are right! I had this in my PATH. For some reason, the indexing is not working in my Yosemite perfectly. The hashing did not take immediate effect. Now, I can see those commands in my command line after 5 hours waiting.

Comment: Glad to hear it works now. Indexing isn't required to call a command in Terminal though, but know that it's working for you it doesn't really matter.

Comment: For me, it matters! I opened a new thread where I summarize the problem which I have noticed in two occasions in my system in nearly low memory states. http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/179448/15504